# how can i fetch paginated json data with a recursive function

Tags: javascript, gitlab, tampermonkey, userscripts

i need some help turning the function below into a recursive function.
it should call itself until a specific http header is not present anymore, then execute the last two functions `fncParse()` and `fncDrawTbl`.
i'm getting the error `recfnc is not a function`.

```
// use gitlab api to fetch json data
// must check response http headers to iterate over all pages
// recursively call the function while there is a 'rel="next"' link header

var filteredJsonData = [];
var parsedJsonData   = [];

recfnc = function() {
    var req = $.getJSON(url, function(jsondata) {
        var hdrlink, linknext, relnext;

        filteredJsonData.push(fncFilter(jsondata));

        try {
            hdrlink  = req.getResponseHeader('link').split(',');
            relnext  = hdrlink.filter(l => l.toLowerCase().indexOf('rel="next"') > -1);
            linknext = relnext[0].split('<')[1].split('>')[0];
        }
        catch (e) { console.log(e); }

        if (linknext) {
            recfnc(linknext);
        }
        else {
            parsedJsonData.push(fncParse(filteredJsonData));
            fncDrawTbl(['Name', 'Issues', 'Hours'], parsedJsonData, '#contentKPI');
        }
    });
}(url);
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason that your function doesn't work assuming that `recfnc =` is just an error in your question not in the original code (it should be `const recfnc=`)

What you are actually storing in the `recfnc` variable is a result of the function call `fn(){}(url)` not the function itself. In your case, `recfnc` variable actually holds `undefined` value.

Change this:

```
recfnc = function(){}

// to:

(function recfnc(){}(url))
```

Comment: after your edit, it works :) spot on. now if you could add some explanation, that would really help me.

Comment: @RASG I have added the explanation